# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. mvc post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ext.net

When I click the update button ,I am getting the null value of TestCaseModel md.I couldnt get the where I am doing wrong.
(I am trying to get the selected value of the combobox)

my model

```
   public class TestCaseModel
    {
       public Product pro  {get;set;}
       public List<ProductCatagory> lst { get; set; }

    }

    public class Product {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }


    }


    public class ProductCatagory {

        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

my controler

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        TestCaseModel md = new TestCaseModel();
        md.lst = new List<ProductCatagory> {
            new ProductCatagory { ID="1",Name="science book"}, 
            new ProductCatagory {ID="2",Name="cartoon book"} 
        };

        md.pro = new Product {Description="here is the des.",Name="Book" };

        return View(md);
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update(TestCaseModel md)
    {


        X.Msg.Notify(new NotificationConfig
        {
            Icon = Icon.Accept,
            Title = "Working",
            Html = md.pro.Name+">>"
        }).Show();


        return this.Direct();
    }
```

and my view

```
  @Html.X().ResourceManager()

   @Html.X().TextFieldFor(m=>m.pro.Name).Flex(1).FieldLabel("ID").Value(@Model.pro.Name)

     @Html.X().ComboBox().FieldLabel("Urun katagori").Flex(1).Store(Html.X().Store().ID("Store41")
    .Model(Html.X().Model().Fields(new ModelField("ID"), new ModelField("Name"))).DataSource(@Model.lst)
    ).ValueField("ID").DisplayField("Name").Value(@Model.pro.Name)


      @Html.X().Button().Text("Update").Icon(Icon.PageSave).DirectClickAction("Update","TestCase")
```

Comment: Please post stack trace

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to really say whats wrong with the code without the stack trace;

however, given what you've shown thus far, I'd say that if you suspect that any of the classes are the problem then you should try initializing all the values in the classes in the constructor.

Try the following:

```
public class TestCaseModel
{
   public Product pro  {get;set;}
   public List<ProductCatagory> lst { get; set; }

   public TestCaseModel(){
      pro = String.Empty;
      lst = new List<ProductCatagory>();
   }
}

public class Product {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Product(){
        Name = String.Empty;
        Description = String.Empty;
    }
}


public class ProductCatagory {

    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ProductCatagory (){
        ID = String.Empty
        Name = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Always explain why the code works and what's different compared to the original code.

Comment: nope I think problem is not to initialize  via constructure

Comment: @sakir, have you defined the Update controller action? Is the controller name "TestCase" in your project? Have you changed the .DirectClickAction?